# Need help copying files

Tags: python-3.x

Is there a way to utilize python to copy files from one machine's program files directory to other local nodes within a domain? I need to automate a manual process of running antivirus updates.

Answer (score 0):

Sure but you may want to look at the security implications of what you're doing.

You probably should do this as a two step process
1) Getting the new file into a location all machines can pull it from
2) Pulling them from the central location to the correct one on the individual machines

Step 1 is probably easiest to attack by pushing them to an HTTP server